# UWP Mvvm Prism ConfirgureContainer Issue

Tags: uwp, prism

I am using Prism in a UWP app. I am registering some start up args for each View Model in

```
    protected override async void ConfigureContainer()
```

I added the async keyword because I wanted to initialise some Database connections which are awaitable in ConfigureContainer(). But now I notice that the application starts (sometimes) with out the startup ags being instatiated causing null ref exceptions. Should I not initialise any connections in this method? Why is it the app not waitng on the ConfigureContainer()? Where should I put Async initialising method calls when app starts up? Here is the method.

```
 protected override async void ConfigureContainer()
    {


        // register a singleton using Container.RegisterType<IInterface, Type>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterInstance<IResourceLoader>(new ResourceLoaderAdapter(new ResourceLoader()));
        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://docdb.etc/"),
             "my key", new ConnectionPolicy() { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct });
        try
        {
            await client.OpenAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("DocumentClient client could not open");
        }
        IDataAccessBM _db = new DataAccessDocDb(client, "ct", "ops");
        AddressSearch addresSearcher = new AddressSearch(_db, 4);
        StartUpArgs startUpArgs = new StartUpArgs
        {
            postCodeApiKey = "anotherKey",
            db = _db,
            fid = "bridge cars",
            dialogService = new DialogService(),
            addressSearcher = addresSearcher
        };
        startUpArgs.zoneSet = await _db.ZoneSetGetActiveAsync("another key");
        Container.RegisterInstance(startUpArgs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put you initialisation code in

```
 protected override  void ConfigureContainer()
```

Put it in:

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
```

The Container is accessable from there and the method is async.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I not initialise any connections in this method?

Not asynchronously, at least. I'd rather create a `ConnectionFactory` that (maybe asynchonously) creates connections on demand.

> Why is it the app not waiting on the ConfigureContainer()?

Because one cannot `await` `void`. This is the reason the use of `async void` is discouraged... it's the `Task` in `async Task` that's `await`ed, not the `async`.

> Where should I put async initialising method calls when app starts up?

There's no such thing as `async` constructors or `async new`. A good start for exploring your options here is [this post by Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

> `Container.RegisterInstance<IResourceLoader>(new ResourceLoaderAdapter(new ResourceLoader()));`

Registering instances is ugly, and unnecessary most of the time (this is an example). If you refactor your code to let the container do its job, your async-initialization-problem will disappear.